# Use data from a session to assign it to a stored procedure variable

Tags: php, database, session, stored-procedures

I have a PHP session which store an id which has been retrieved from a table. Now I want to use that id in another db table.

```
$query = sqlsrv_query("SELECT Customer_ID FROM Customer WHERE Email='$email' AND password = '$password'",$conn);
$result = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
#checks if the search was made
    if($result === false)
    {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    if($result === true)
    {
        ['Active'] = $result;
        echo 'User Active = ' . $_SESSION['Active']
    }
```

So, the array 'Active' store the 'Customer_ID' and I want to use it in another table. How do I assign that id to a variable in a stored procedure?